# How to kill a background job run by bash file

Tags: bash, shell

I've set a bash file for start PHP and Webpack server locally like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd my-php-serivce/
php -S localhost:8000 -t public &
cd ../my-react-app
npm start &
```

After I run the bash file by `./start.sh` I closed the terminal,

how can I found and kill the process? I've tried `jobs`, `ps`, `fg` but cannot found the process. Thanks.

Comment: try `pgrep php`

Comment: If you did not use `nohup` chances are your script terminated when you closed the terminal.

Comment: Thanks @balki this command is good but it will show all php service I'm running without the name

Comment: For a proper script, you have to save the pids in some file to find and kill later. If not, you have to guess from the ps output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should store your PID into file to use later. as below:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd my-php-serivce/
php -S localhost:8000 -t public & echo $! > my_php_pid
cd ../my-react-app
npm start &
```

When you want to kill it, just:

```
kill -9 $(cat my-php-serivce/my_php_pid)
```

But the best way is you must use Daemons to mange your processes. [REF](https://www.linux.com/learn/managing-linux-daemons-init-scripts)